# Can I replace just part of a 1x6 roof deck with OSB?

Tags: roof, roofing, materials, decking, sheathing

Redoing Roof, Roof Decking is 1x6 inch planks, and some OSB so the sheathing is mixed materials.

Is it ok to replace the lower half of the roof with 3/4 or 1/2 inch plywood and keep the top half 1x6s? I figure as long as the lower part of the roof stays lower than the top part it'd be fine, but I'd like to double check so I wouldn't have to re-do it if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can. I've done just that with a 1950s home I owned to patch in where the chimney came through and to replace rotted boards across an entire section. Just use spacers between the OSB sheets as is common practice to create 1/8" gaps. (Or use 16d nails as spacers with 3/4" sheathing--the sheets are sized for that.)

Also, use suitable fasteners. 8d nails are good for 1/2" material, but you might go a bit larger (10d or 12d) for 3/4" material.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the H-clips, I picked up a bag with the plywood. I'm going to be using 10d nails 6 inches apart for the edges and 12 inches for the truss. From what I've read and researched that's what you're supposed to do.